# python Tkinter focus_set() is not working properly on capturing key press event

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, setfocus

there are two methods in the below code, one is for capturing mouse clicks another is for the key press. I want to focus_set on the key press rather than the mouse clicks but if I use  focus_set inside the key press function then it doesn't work. but if I put it inside the mouse click it works and the key functions works just fine.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

text = ''
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)


def key(event):

    frame.focus_set() # here is the focus set which is not working
    global text

    text += event.char
    print (test)

def callback(event):
    #but If I put that same line here, it works
    print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focus_set` only affects events that fire after it is called, and it only affects keyboard events, not mouse clicks. Calling it in an event handler simply cannot effect the event being handled.

Comment: thanks for the answer, also I want to know, if I return the text value from the key method and then make a new variable outside the method like a = key("what will be the parameter?") because the function is taking event object as the parameter. what should be in the parameter for this key method

Comment: @MD.FazlaRabby: Since `key` uses data from the event, if you want to call it directly and save the return value, you're going to have to pass it an object that has a `char` parameter since that's what your callback requires.

Comment: thanks for your reply, Does python have a "char" variable? It will be really helpful if you could give me a demonstration/example